# Why did Harry want to kill Brandon?

Tags: gungrave

I still don't understand why Harry killed Brandon. He was Harry's best friend and the most loyal member he had.

Is it because he was jealous of him because he was Maria's boyfriend, or was it for another reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harry wanted to take leadership of the syndicate, and the only way to do that was to assassinate Big Daddy, a way that Brandon does not approve with as he was still very loyal to Millennion's founder and leader. Brandon even left Maria when her dad, Big Daddy, disagreed with their relationship. So Harry betrayed both Brandon and Big Daddy, killing them both, in order to take control of Millennion.

Comment: Tough luck.
Very sad truth.